# CoffeeScript class broke after minification

Tags: dojo, coffeescript

I have simple class (with Dojo):

```
define ["dojo/request", "dojo/html", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom"], (request, html, observe, dom) ->
   class Foo
     constructor: (@a) ->
       alert @a
```

I create a new object of this class at different file:

```
require ["Libraries/Foo", "dojo/domReady!"], (Foo) ->
   t = new Foo "test"
```

When I compile the Foo class file into JS, everything works without problem, but when I minify the JS output with for example http://jscompress.com code will broke up.

After minification code looks like:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
(function(){define(["dojo/request","dojo/html","dojo/on","dojo/dom"],function(e,t,n,r){var i;return i=function(){function e(e){this.a=e;alert(this.a)}return e}()})}).call(this);
```

At console (Safari, Chrome) I can see:

```
TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Foo("test")')
```

But when I reformat code using tool at my IDE, everything works OK.

Code after reformation:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
(function () {
    define(["dojo/request", "dojo/html", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom"], function (e, t, n, r) {
        var i;
        return i = function () {
            function e(e) {
                this.a = e;
                alert(this.a)
            }

            return e
        }()
    })
}).call(this);
```

Where can be problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Using `async: true` in Dojo config.